# sed replace ;" content with ';"

Tags: shell, text-processing, sed, quoting

I have files that contain `;"` and I need it replaced with `';"`

The following sed command does not work:

```
sed -i "s/;"/';"/g" /root/bashy.sh
```

How can I do this? The solution doesn't have to be `sed`.

Comment: You should be more specific about 'does not work' - what error do you get?  And what effects?

Answer (score 1):

This is a shell mistake, not a sed one - your quotes need to be quoted:

```
sed "s/;\"/';\"/g"
```

Or even

```
sed s/';"'/"'"';"'/g
```

if you don't like backslashes...

Comment: Thank you. How would I do it for spaces? sed -i "s/= /= '/g"

Answer (score 1):

With GNU sed:

```
sed -i.bak 's/;"/\x27&/g' file
```

POSIX sed:

```
sed -e "s/;\"/'&/g" < file > file.out
```

Comment: Thank you. How would I do it for spaces? sed -i "s/= /= '/g"

Comment: @Teddy291: `sed -i.bak 's/= /&\x27/g' file`